# In Ember, is using submodels for static select values a good idea?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm using Ember-CLI and Ember-Data.

I have a `Product` which can have many `ProductStatuses`. My statuses are static so I can include them in the app itself. Is it a good idea to use `DS.hasMany` for this kind of attribute?

If yes, can you show me an example of how I would tell ember to exclude the submodel `ProductStatus` from sync operations and how I would store it's predefined values locally? Using `DS.Store.push` maybe?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a good idea. Why? As you said, you would have to exclude this model from any sync operations which means, that eventually it will become a simple array. I think that better solution is to define them globally in app config, e.g. in `config/environment.js` like this:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    (...)
    appConfig: {
      productStatuses: ["status one", "status two"]
    }
  };
  (...)
}
```

Then in your app where it will be needed you can import the `ENV` module and use it as you want (`import ENV from "appName/config/environment";`).